# Call aspx page inside php script

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I wants to call aspx page inside php script . And wants to return a value from that aspx to php .
I have done like this, But not return anything 
 myphp.php

```
<?php $url = "http://xxx.co/aa/Default.aspx" ;
$param = "?" . "Field1=" . $num . "&Field2=" . $name . ";
header('Location: ' . $url . $param);
$_COOKIE['name'];
$cookies = getCookies();
$sessionname = $cookies['name'];
echo 'name is' .$sessionname;
?>
```

Myasp.aspx

```
 Session("Session_ASPUserID") = (Request.QueryString("Field1"));
 Session("Session_ASPUserName") = (Request.QueryString("Field2"));
  HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("name");
    cookie.Secure = true;
    cookie.Value = "Joe";
    Response.Redirect("myphp.php");
```

please help to correct the idea

Answer (score 0):

get the file contents and assign to a variable like.

```
$data = file_get_contents($url . $param);
```

then check if your required result is returned as

```
if(strpos($data,'looking_for')>=0){
    //code if found what you are looking for
}else{
    //code if NOT found what you are looking for
}
```